# Is Query<> Obsolete in NHibernate 4.0 Version?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, queryover

I am trying to use session.Query<> to query on my list but its not appearing on my intellisense. That's why I am using QueryOver instead:

```
using (ISession session = NHibernateSession.OpenSession())
{
    var customer = session.QueryOver<Customer>().List();
}

return View();
```

Is `Query<>` already obsolete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Query` is an extension method:

```
namespace NHibernate.Linq
{
    public static class LinqExtensionMethods
    {
        public static IQueryable<T> Query<T>(this ISession session)
        {
            ...
```

So, just be sure you have this statement in your C# file

```
using NHibernate.Linq;
```